# styling with div blocks

Tags: css, html

I have a single line (left screen to right side)  that I want to format so that the form look justified regardless the number of elements as the style is repeated (between 2 and 5 elements)

Why are the div tags overlapping each other when I inspect the following rendered HTML?

```
<div class="grid_7 ">
    <div class="grid_2">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("F1FirstName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="push_1 grid_2 float-left ">
        <asp:Label Text="Last Name: " ID="LastName" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div class="grid_3 float-left">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxLastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("F2LastName")%>' />
    </div>
</div>
```

[EDIT]`.float-left 
{
float:left;
}

.float-right 
{
float:right;
}`

`.container_12 .push_1 {
    left: 80px;
}`

`.container_12,
.container_16 {
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 960px;
    height: auto;
}`

`.grid_12 {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}`

All is wrapped in the "container_12" and "grid_12" within that container within the master page.  Grids are evenly spaced portions within the container  so I will not include that code. Pushes/pulls are left right movements of the div in and all defined with "position:relative"  the style float-left was my attempt to manually align these divs and simply assign the property "float-left"  Please let me know if more is needed.

Comment: Not entirely sure what your code is doing, but a hunch that has something to do with your fixed width + padding.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to provide all applicable styles from your stylesheet.

eg: grid_7, grid_2, grid_3, push_1, etc

Comment: "Grids are evenly spaced portions within the container so I will not include that code."

You're asking us to fix the positioning of the divs and you're not giving us all the CSS rules you're applying to them.  How can we do that?  You need to explain yourself better.